# Displaying Loop data using Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm attempting to display links from my navigation table in my SQL server. My query to select links is as follows however when used none of the links display or only one link (IE not taking the loop into account)

```
$query = "SELECT link FROM navigation WHERE permission<='3'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
echo '<li>';
echo $row['link'];
echo '</li>';
```

I have also tried using

```
$query = "SELECT link FROM navigation WHERE permissions<='3'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
echo '<li>';
echo $row['link'];
echo '</li>';
```

My original code was a simple mysql_select and was

```
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM navigation WHERE enabled='1' AND permission<='3'");
            while ($row=
            mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                echo '<li>';
                echo $row['link'];
                echo '</li>';
                }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
echo '<li>';
echo $row['link'];
echo '</li>';
```

Should look like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
   echo '<li>';
   echo $row['link'];
   echo '</li>';
}
```

You have to define the code block as such.

Comment: Thanks, Massive overlook on my part; I think I just needed a second pair of eyes on that. I'll accept as soon as it will let me.

Comment: No worries, happens to me all the time.